# Plotly: Interactive graph with 'lines+markers' mode using plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly

`df`:

```
                        id      timestamp               data    Date            Start   
timestamp                                   
2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 40250   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 20.0    2020-01-15      NaN 
2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 40251   2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 19.5    2020-01-15      0.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 40256   2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 20.0    2020-01-15      1.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 40257   2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 20.5    2020-01-15      0.0 
2020-01-15 09:01:50.993 40310   2020-01-15 09:01:50.993 21.0    2020-01-15      0.0 
2020-01-15 09:01:51.093 40311   2020-01-15 09:01:51.093 21.5    2020-01-15      0.0 
2020-01-15 09:51:01.890 40336   2020-01-15 09:51:01.890 22.0    2020-01-15      0.0
```

I want to plot an interactive graph using `plotly.express`, colour by `Start`(which is dummy variable), with `mode='lines+markers'`. But I couldn't add the line. At the moment, using code below

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x="timestamp", y="data", title='xxx')
fig = px.scatter(df, x="timestamp", y="data",color='Start')   
fig.show()
```

I obtained plot 
[image]

---

Update:

Tried:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['data'])
fig.add_scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['data'], marker_color=df['Start'])
```

which returned:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your code the figure object is being overwritten, i.e. the scatter plot is replacing the line plot rather than being added to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2020-01-15 06:12:49.213', '2020-01-15 06:12:49.313', '2020-01-15 08:05:10.083', '2020-01-15 08:05:10.183',
                                 '2020-01-15 09:01:50.993', '2020-01-15 09:01:51.093', '2020-01-15 09:51:01.890'],
                   'data': [20.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0],
                   'start': [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]})


fig = px.line(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['data'])
fig.add_scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['data'], mode='markers', marker_color=df['start'], marker_size=10)

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='#bababa', showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It achieved the line graph, but not the markers, or colour by column `df['start']`. Please see question update.

Comment: I updated my answer, try adding `mode='markers'` to the scatter trace.

Comment: It's working! Btw, may I ask why the previous issue in the update? And is it possible to change the background colour of the plot?

Comment: The issue was that in my case the `px.scatter` was using `mode='markers'` by default, while in your case it was using `mode='lines'` by default, that's why you were getting two line plots instead of a line plot and a scatter plot. This may be due to the fact that we are using different versions of plotly. You can change the plot background color in the layout dictionary, i.e. instead of setting `plot_bgcolor='#bababa'` (where #bababa is the hex code of a dark gray) you can set `plot_bgcolor='white'` or any other color.